# LTSP Thin Clients can't see usb flash drives and other devices

Tags: usb, scanner, ltsp, ltsp-client

I have Ubuntu 14.04 64bit as an LTSP server and I have several 32bit thin clients attached to it. They have USB keyboards and mice and they work fine, but they don't recognize USB drives, scanners and printers. Right now I just need to connect a scanner to one of the thin clients. If I connect the scanner to the LTSP server everything is fine and I can scan. Typing lsusb shows me the scanner. However, when I plug it in a thin client, I can't see it. If I type lsusb on a thin client I see the devices connected to the LTSP server, not the thin client.

Here is my lts.conf:

```
[default]
X_MODE = 1280X1024
X_COLOR_DEPTH=16
LOCALDEV=True
NBD_SWAP=True
LDM_DIRECTX=True
SCANNER=True
```

I have built the image and restarted the thin clients but nothing.